# How to export a table as a Markdown table when using org-md-export-to-markdown?

Tags: org-export, markdown

The current behavior of `org-md-export-to-markdown` is to export Org Mode tables as HTML tables. I would like tables to be exported as Markdown tables (as explained [here](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#tables)).

Answer (score 3):

## Use the ox-gfm package

The `gfm` part in the package name stands for "Github Flavored Markdown".

This package is available at MELPA. The source code can be found at [this](https://github.com/larstvei/ox-gfm) repository at Github. A minimal working example is shown below.

Consider the following Org Mode file

```
* The first heading

| word    | number |
|---------+--------|
| one     |      1 |
| ten     |     10 |
| hundred |    100 |

* The second heading

#+begin_src bash
echo "Hello World"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
Hello World
#+end_example
```

By using `org-gfm-export-as-markdown` (function defined in the `ox-gfm` package) in the Org Mode buffer, the newly created buffer would look like

````markdown
# The first heading

| word    | number |
|------- |------ |
| one     | 1      |
| ten     | 10     |
| hundred | 100    |


# The second heading

```bash
echo "Hello World"
```

```
Hello World
```
````

## System information

```bash
emacs --version
```

```
GNU Emacs 27.2
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

```lisp
(org-version)
```

```
9.4.4
```